# How can I queue data via a web service for bulk insert to DB?

Tags: database, wcf, locking, message-queue, bulkinsert

So here's my current situation:

I have a bunch of client apps that are currently inserting to a central DB one record at a time. This of course causes a lot of overhead for the DB, along with potential "pausing" issues for the client app as it waits for the DB operation to complete.

So what I'd like to do instead:

I'd like each client app to talk to a web service for writing each record, rather than directly to the DB. The web service will then write the data to a file, which will then be processed at a given interval. I figure that way I can do a bulk insert of X number of records every 5 minutes or so, rather than doing a single insert thousands of times in that same 5 minutes.  The client app will write to a file on the local machine if the web service is unavailable, and then once it's available again it'll send each record in the local file.  If the DB is down, the web service will just keep writing to the file until such time as it can successfully do the bulk insert.  So the client apps can keep going, even if there's a failure of either, and it'll just catch up when things are back up.

The problem:

So I assume that if I have the web service try to write to the same file this will be an issue, as I'll have hundreds of instances trying to do so at the same time.  I considered writing each record to its own file, and then moving all the existing files to another directory for processing at the given interval, but then I have to deal with hundreds or even thousands of individual files, which I'm not particularly thrilled about.

So is there a better way to handle this?  Is it possible to lock the web service local file without it causing a terrible bottleneck or deadlock condition?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crazy idea : as the records come in, serialize them to JSON and chuck them into a separate NoSQL DB. You can scale that as much as you'd like.

Have a service running which monitors that NoSql db and every now and then, say every hour, gets all the records, does a batch insert into the main sql db and removes the inserted records from the NoSQL source.

The point here is to avoid putting pressure on your main production db.

You could also use a messaging queue instead of a NoSQL db, same principle applies. Record goes into queue, queue builds up, service picks all messages and does its thing. It does feel a lot safer though with a second database approach. If your messaging system goes down, you've just lost all unprocessed records.

-- Added more info here

A NoSQL db can handle concurrent inserts just fine and they can scale easily as well, nothing to worry about on that side.

Trying to concurrently write to one file will quickly get you into trouble and you'll need to think about how you'll handle that. By the time you actually do it, you might as well stick to the database approach. Plus you get all the good stuff with a database, you can backup data if that's what you desire or you can sync it, you can handle large amounts of data. You have lots of options basically. I'd seriously recommend not even trying to write to files with something like this.

Now, as for batch inserts I would avoid using an ORM like Entity Framework for this. If your data is relatively simple I would just use the service to create a SQl script containing all the inserts and just run it against the database. It's actually very easy to have a scripted approach like this. The advantages here are multiple :

1. Execution speed
2. Data backup and integrity checks - you can compare what was in DB and what is in the script.

Here's an example of how to run such a script from command line : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx

You have options, just use whatever approach works better for you. Give it a go with ORM batch inserts first, time it and if you're unhappy then you can use the other scripted approach or maybe one I haven't even considered yet.

Comment: I'll probably end up going with your first suggestion.  I'm curious though as to how something like this avoids the same type of concurrency violations that I would have if I were to try to write to a simple text file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not writing a file to begin with. It isn't terribly difficult to have a native (eg C++) program listening to a port which these clients talk to, and where this program uses a multiple producer single consumer queue to aggregate all records received in memory until a certain threshold is reached. You could set it so that at say 1000 records, or at 5 minutes since previous commit it will do the mass insert automatically.

Writing files would require too much locking and state management to deal with the volume, and if you limit it to one file per IP (as you pointed out) thousands of files being read/written will not be much better.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a message queue for the reason Andrei mentioned below.  If the machine goes down, I've lost everything that was in memory with no way to recover.

Comment: that's just one implementation, instead of waiting for the thresholds to be reached it could constantly be inserting everything it gets. Then it just is there to work as an aggregator, and no more lost data..

Comment: But then if the DB is down, it can't do the insert and it's not actually writing to the hard drive to begin with, so the queue keeps piling up and then could be lost anyway.

Comment: This kind of queue would work exceptionally well sitting in front of the database which Andrei suggested.